# How to take multiple user text input values, add them together with javascript and return the value on page in a <p>

Tags: javascript, html, input, innerhtml

I am very new to Javascript and am looking for a solution to better understand how this works.

I am making a simple budget app with various user text inputs. What I want to accomplish is to store these user inputs inside variables within JS, have them added, possibly compared, then return a total on the page when the user clicks a button in the empty paragraph element. Here is a sample of the html code (I have only included two of the inputs as they will work the same and just need an understanding of the concept):

```
<ul>
            <li><p>Money In:</p></li>
            <br>
            <li class="inputHeading">Current Balance</li>
            <li><input type="text" class="input" id="balanceInput"></li>
            <li><p>Money Out:</p></li>
            <br>
            <li class="inputHeading">Rent</li>
            <li><input type="text" class="input" id="rentInput"></li>
            <li><input type="button" class="button" value="AMOUNT LEFT" onclick="calcTotal()"></li>
            <li class="output" id="amountOutput"><p></p></li>
</ul>
```

I have researched various methods but most of what I find is far more complex than I can currently understand. I wanted to see if anyone could both suggest and explain a solution to how to do this. Your help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can store the input in js with document.getElementById("id").value
However this will be stored in string, so you need to change it into integer/float if you want to calculate the total
parseFloat() is the method to parse string text into float values. 
In the example you provided, the values is current balance and rent, hence I think it is more suitable to find the difference instead of adding them together.

```js
function calcTotal() {
  var inputbal = parseFloat(document.getElementById("balanceInput").value);
  var inputrent = parseFloat(document.getElementById("rentInput").value);
  var balance = inputbal - inputrent;
  document.getElementById("balance").innerHTML = balance.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>Money In:</p>
  </li>
  <br>
  <li class="inputHeading">Current Balance</li>
  <li><input type="text" class="input" id="balanceInput"></li>
  <li>
    <p>Money Out:</p>
  </li>
  <br>
  <li class="inputHeading">Rent</li>
  <li><input type="text" class="input" id="rentInput"></li>
  <li><input type="button" class="button" value="AMOUNT LEFT" onclick="calcTotal()"></li>
  <li class="output" id="amountOutput">
    <p></p>
  </li>
</ul>

<p id="balance"></p>
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your insight/input. So with float values I would be able to essentially perform calculations with the variables? Am I following you there? Also, since you used the same calcTotal() that appears in the onlick does that mean that when a user clicks the button they function runs? Lastly, in the added id=''balance''> will that display the output? You're right, in this case it would make better sense to subtract, however I have many more inputs that I didn't list because I want to be able to apply what you've taught me so that I actually understand.

Comment: Yes, you understand all of them correctly. Just note that if you didn't parse the input data into float or integers, the data will be added as a string. For example, 12+13 = 1213.
Side Note: You can actually run the code in this website and test it by clicking on the blue button ("Run code snippet") just right below the code.